# MCMC.OTU modify plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using MCMC.OTU I am trying to rotate the text on the x axis.  I am using the dataset green.data that comes with the package.  Following the example code provided in the package information, I want to modify the following line

```
ss=OTUsummary(mm,gs,summ.plot=TRUE)
```

to include

```
(axis.text.x= element_text(angle=-90))
```

but when I add it with either I comma or a + I get Error: unexpected ","

How do you modify the plots in MCMC.OTU

Answer (score 0):

`ss` is a list of three items, so you need to extract the ggplot part first:

```
p1 <- ss$ggPlot
```

Then you can add `theme()` to modify the plot:

```
p1 + theme(axis.text.x= element_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]